# How is いい being used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, japanese-to-english

> もしも僕に心があるならどうやってそれをみつければいいの

I understand the sentence translates along the lines of "If I had a heart, how would I find it?" And I know "いい" means "good/fine/etc" but I'm not sure how to fit that into the translation. Unless it's serving as another word I don't know.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The most common phrase with that form would be "どうすればいい？” = "What should I do?"... "どう食べればいい？” = "How should I eat it?".  Effectively "What is the *right* way to do this", "What is the *correct* way to eat this".

Answer (score 1):

`conditional form (eba-form) + いい/よい` is a very common pattern which literally means "will be good if ～", but essentially means just "can" or "should". See: [Learn JLPT N3 Grammar: ばいい (ba ii)](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%B0%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-baii/)

- **どうやって**: how
- **それ**: it
- **を**: (object marker)
- **見つければいい**: should find / can find

  - 見つければ: conditional form of 見つける
  - いい: good
- **の**: explanatory-の used to seek for clarification

Thus "How should/can I find it?"

Note that this pattern is so common that いい/よい may even be omitted.

> - 何をすれば？
>     What should I do?
> - 行けば？
>     Why don't you go?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I see why it's confusing as いい／良い is usually straight up "good".

どうすれば良いですか？　- how can I do this? Direct translation of Japanese is "To get a good result, how?" This is how we'd ask for instructions.

Similarly the direct translation of

> もしも僕に心があるならどうやってそれをみつければいいの

If I have a heart, how would I get a good result of finding it.

Hope this helps.

In this particular one, it sounds like a line from lyrics, it's more like "I can't find my soul. I don't think I have it."